# WARN: Tried to pass invalid video frame, marking as broken: Your frame has data type int64, but we require uint8

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, gcloud

I am doing some Udemy AI courses and came across with one that "teaches" a bidimensional cheetah how to walk. I was doing the exercises on my computer, but it takes too much time. I decided to use Google Cloud to run the code and see the results some hours after. Nevertheless, when I run the code I get the following error " WARN: Tried to pass 
invalid video frame, marking as broken: Your frame has data type int64, but we require uint8 (i.e. RGB values from 0-255)".

After the code is executed, I see into the folder and I don't see any videos (just the meta info).

Some more info (if it helps):
I have a 1 CPU (4g), SSD Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I have not tried anything yet to solve it because I don´t know what to try. Im looking for solutions on the web, but nothing I could try.

This is the code

```
import os 
import numpy as np
import gym
from gym import wrappers
import pybullet_envs


class Hp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.nb_steps = 1000
        self.episode_lenght =   1000
        self.learning_rate = 0.02
        self.nb_directions = 32
        self.nb_best_directions = 32
        assert self.nb_best_directions <= self.nb_directions
        self.noise = 0.03
        self.seed = 1
        self.env_name = 'HalfCheetahBulletEnv-v0'


class Normalizer():
    def __init__(self, nb_inputs):
        self.n = np.zeros(nb_inputs)
        self.mean = np.zeros(nb_inputs)
        self.mean_diff = np.zeros(nb_inputs)
        self.var = np.zeros(nb_inputs)

    def observe(self, x):
        self.n += 1.
        last_mean = self.mean.copy()
        self.mean += (x - self.mean) / self.n
        #abajo es el online numerator update
        self.mean_diff += (x - last_mean) * (x - self.mean)
        #abajo online computation de la varianza
        self.var = (self.mean_diff / self.n).clip(min = 1e-2)  

    def normalize(self, inputs):
        obs_mean = self.mean
        obs_std = np.sqrt(self.var)
        return (inputs - obs_mean) / obs_std

class Policy():
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        self.theta = np.zeros((output_size, input_size))

    def evaluate(self, input, delta = None, direction = None):
        if direction is None:
            return self.theta.dot(input)
        elif direction == 'positive':
            return (self.theta + hp.noise * delta).dot(input)
        else:
            return (self.theta - hp.noise * delta).dot(input)

    def sample_deltas(self):
        return [np.random.randn(*self.theta.shape) for _ in range(hp.nb_directions)]

    def update (self, rollouts, sigma_r):
        step = np.zeros(self.theta.shape)
        for r_pos, r_neg, d in rollouts:
            step += (r_pos - r_neg) * d
        self.theta += hp.learning_rate / (hp.nb_best_directions * sigma_r) * step


def explore(env, normalizer, policy, direction = None, delta = None):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    num_plays = 0.
    #abajo puede ser promedio de las rewards
    sum_rewards = 0
    while not done and num_plays < hp.episode_lenght:
        normalizer.observe(state)
        state = normalizer.normalize(state)
        action = policy.evaluate(state, delta, direction)
        state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        reward = max(min(reward, 1), -1)
        #abajo sería poner un promedio
        sum_rewards += reward
        num_plays += 1
    return sum_rewards

def train (env, policy, normalizer, hp):
    for step in range(hp.nb_steps):
        #iniciar las perturbaciones deltas y los rewards positivos/negativos
        deltas = policy.sample_deltas()
        positive_rewards = [0] * hp.nb_directions
        negative_rewards = [0] * hp.nb_directions
        #sacar las rewards en la dirección positiva
        for k in range(hp.nb_directions):
            positive_rewards[k] = explore(env, normalizer, policy, direction = 'positive', delta = deltas[k])
        #sacar las rewards en dirección negativo
        for k in range(hp.nb_directions):
            negative_rewards[k] = explore(env, normalizer, policy, direction = 'negative', delta = deltas[k])
        #sacar todas las rewards para sacar la desvest
        all_rewards = np.array(positive_rewards + negative_rewards)
        sigma_r = all_rewards.std()
        #acomodar los rollauts por el max (r_pos, r_neg) y seleccionar la mejor dirección
        scores = {k:max(r_pos, r_neg) for k, (r_pos, r_neg) in enumerate(zip(positive_rewards, negative_rewards))}
        order = sorted(scores.keys(), key = lambda x:scores[x])[:hp.nb_best_directions]
        rollouts = [(positive_rewards[k], negative_rewards[k], deltas[k]) for k in order]
        #actualizar policy
        policy.update (rollouts, sigma_r)
        #poner el final reward del policy luego del update
        reward_evaluation = explore (env, normalizer, policy)
        print('Paso: ', step, 'Lejania: ', reward_evaluation)

def mkdir(base, name):
    path = os.path.join(base, name)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    return path
work_dir = mkdir('exp', 'brs')
monitor_dir = mkdir(work_dir, 'monitor')

hp = Hp()
np.random.seed(hp.seed)
env = gym.make(hp.env_name)
env = wrappers.Monitor(env, monitor_dir, force = True)
nb_inputs = env.observation_space.shape[0]
nb_outputs = env.action_space.shape[0]
policy = Policy(nb_inputs, nb_outputs)
normalizer = Normalizer(nb_inputs)
train(env, policy, normalizer, hp)
```

Comment: I see that you are using the Gym library. I have seen in their [code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/c33cfd8b2cc8cac6c346bc2182cd568ef33b8821/gym/wrappers/monitoring/video_recorder.py#L299) that they are expecting data type uint8, no other data types.

Furthermore, I have seen this [Github repository](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/25cc1fa386447771e3a19c1470578a995eb06f9e/examples/pybullet/gym/pybullet_envs/ARS/ars.py#L230) where I can see the user is parsing some argunments, and maybe this could be helpful for you.
Let me know if this was fine!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I think it was either a thing of an old version of ffmpeg or another compatibility issue (this is my first try with linux and I could not update ffmpeg properly). I changed my virtual environment from Ubunto 16.04 to Debian. It worked perfectly.